# Can you boot mac os x of a logical partition?

Tags: partitioning, osx-lion, multi-boot

I currently have a win7 and ubuntu dual boot on my laptop (Sony VAIO) but want to add os x for a triple boot setup.

Thanks to system reserved and hidden backup partitions I have long since run out of primary partitions on my hard drive.

My question is, can I boot os x from a logical partition? If so, will I be able to keep just one boot menu (currently grub) and choose which os to boot from there?

Would there be any benefit for me to try and rearrange my partitions (major hassle) to get os x on a primary?

Comment: What bootloader do you have; are you using the Windows 7 loader or the Ubuntu loader?  Depending which one you have will be how you proceed - basically, you'd boot the partition using the bootloader rather than your BIOS directly which can only boot primary partitions.

Comment: I'm using the ubuntu loader (grub?). So it shouldn't be too difficult to just edit the grub bootloader to add an entry pointing to the logical partition with os x on it?

Comment: It's been a while since I used grub, but yes, just check the documentation with grub about booting logical partitions and if it says you can do it, I don't see why not.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that it was dependent on grub as opposed to os x.

Comment: Unless it's Apple hardware, booting it is likely illegal.

Comment: @JOTN I was suprised by your comment, but sure enough a quick google reveals that it is against the EULA. Whether it is illegal or not, it's for the courts in my country to decide whenever Apple decides to sue me for EULA violation.